# On wayland, why is my default Gtk display an X11Display?

Tags: python, x11, wayland, gtk4

I'm learning GTK4 and working with wayland (hyprland) on linux.

When I try to retrieve the default display, my python code returns an X11Display.
I figured out that the `GDK_BACKEND` environment variable was not set to `wayland`.

However, my question is, why is the code even able to return an X11Monitor?
Could the reason be that it is using XWayland? Are there potential problems (overhead etc) when accessing X11Monitor on wayland?

also, to quote https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/wayland.html#wayland_display:

> The GDK Wayland backend provides support for running GTK applications under a Wayland compositor. To run your application in this way, select the Wayland backend by setting GDK_BACKEND=wayland.
>
> On UNIX, the Wayland backend is enabled by default, so you don’t need to do anything special when compiling it, and everything should “just work.”

So why is it not enabled by default on my system? should hyprland to set this variable?

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

display = Gdk.Display.get_default()
assert display is not None

print(display.__class__)

monitors = display.get_monitors()

for monitor in monitors:
    print(monitor.__class__)
```

output:

```
<class 'gi.repository.GdkX11.X11Display'>
<class 'gi.repository.GdkX11.X11Monitor'>
<class 'gi.repository.GdkX11.X11Monitor'>
```

output when setting `GDK_BACKEND=wayland`:

```
<class '__gi__.GdkWaylandDisplay'>
<class '__gi__.GdkWaylandMonitor'>
<class '__gi__.GdkWaylandMonitor'>
```

Comment: Probably depend on your environment. I have tested your code on Gnome in Fedora and get `<class '__gi__.GdkWaylandDisplay'>` . The variable GDK_BACKEND is not set

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you launch your app from a program that is using XWayland. For example if you are using an IDE or terminal that uses XWayland and run your app it will use the X11 backend if you don't also have the enviornment variable set.

An example of this is launching from VSCode if you have not configured it to run on wayland.

So make sure you are launching the app from a true wayland app and it should work without needing the environment variable.